# Scroll to post when linked to a comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks

When I get a notification about a comment and I click on that link then I get redirected to the comment and it is highlighted. That is generally great.

But almost every time I need the context of the post to understand the comment. For instance  those "Thank you" comments. I need to scroll up to see which post is meant.

[image: Scroll]

Could the link to the comment scroll in a way to make as much as possible of the post visible and not just put the comment on the top of the browser?

Comment: Also, I feel it would help if the highlight lasted a bit longer (or simply forever).

Comment: However such a feature would get implemented, the current behavior is less than ideal simply because it is poor UX.  As suggested, almost 90% of the time, you need to scroll up for context.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/post/4112838.aspx